# Normal approximation of tail probability in binomial distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, reference-request, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

From the [Berry Esseen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry-Esseen_theorem) I know, that $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|P(B_n \le x)-\Phi(x)|\in O\left(\frac 1{\sqrt n}\right)$$ whereby $B_n$ has the standardized binomial distribution and $N$ has the standardized normal distribution. I can prove this for $x\approx 0$ with [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) and a similar proof shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem).

Unfortunately Stirling's approximation becomes worse the bigger $|x|$ is, so that I can only provide that

$$\sup_{|x| \le c}|P(B_n \le x)-\Phi(x)|\in O\left(\frac 1{\sqrt n}\right)$$ for a fixed $c > 0$.

**My question:** Is there a good proof for $\sup_{|x| > c}|P(B_n \le x)-\Phi(x)|\in O\left(\frac 1{\sqrt n}\right)$? How can I estimate the error of the difference in the tail probability of the binomial distribution to the normal distribution?

**Note:** [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality) does not provide the right convergence speed. As zhoraster shows [in his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438737/finding-an-error-estimation-for-the-de-moivre-laplace-theorem/1443489#1443489) to [Finding an error estimation for the De Moivre–Laplace theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438737/finding-an-error-estimation-for-the-de-moivre-laplace-theorem), also [Chernoff's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) does not provide the right convergence speed, too. That's why I am looking for another method. I also want to use more easy and direct approximations than [Stein's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein's_method) which is used in the proof of the Berry Esseen theorem.

**Update:** I reasked this question on MO, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220030/normal-approximation-of-tail-probability-in-binomial-distribution

Comment: The question does not seem no be very different from the another one. Anyway, I wanted to make a different comment: it is enough to estimate $\sup_{c<|x|<c\sqrt{\log n}}\cdots$. I would recommend trying to write estimates form Balazs and Toth's paper using more terms in the Taylor formula for $\log(1+x)$. Then it might happen (and why not?) that the cubic terms somehow cancel out, or at least some big portion of them.

Comment: You are right, an answer to [Point of maximal error in the normal approximation of the binomial distribution](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441275/point-of-maximal-error-in-the-normal-approximation-of-the-binomial-distribution) implies an answer to this question... Thanks also for your suggestion! I will try to follow it...

Comment: By the way, in your pictures, the next term of Edgeworth expansion is clearly visible (especially the first one).

Comment: @zhoraster: Thanks for your comment, from which I have an idea: Can the Edgeworth expansion be used to find a proof of [Point of maximal error in the normal approximation of the binomial distribution](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441275/point-of-maximal-error-in-the-normal-approximation-of-the-binomial-distribution?lq=1)? Unfortunately I do not know much about those expansions, but I will study this topic in the following days...

Comment: Highly unlikely... I believe that writing additional terms of log expansion will lead you to something similar.

Comment: A lot of what's been going on here goes over my head, but it seems to me that if you can run your estimate for linearly growing $c$, then you should be able to manage the "very large" $c$ with Cramer's theorem.

Comment: @Ian: That's right. Unfortunately I only managed to prove  $\sup_{|x| \le c}|P(B_n \le x)-\Phi(x)|\in O\left(\frac 1{\sqrt n}\right)$ with fixed $c > 0$. When $c$ grows I loose convergence speed...

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to notice that you have standardized. That means that you only need to get your estimate for $c$ on the order of $\sqrt{n}$ before Cramer's theorem kicks in. (When $B_n$ deviates from $0$ by $d$, the underlying binomial deviates from $np$ by $d\sqrt{np(1-p)}$.) What happens on this order? Still problems? (Also I see now that zhoraster has pointed out something much stronger than I am saying already...)

Comment: @Ian: With any needed growth I will loose convergence speed (when I only use Stirling's approximation in my proof)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See the answer on mathoverflow.com](https://mathoverflow.net/a/220199/56668) by [Iosif Pinelis](https://mathoverflow.net/users/36721/iosif-pinelis).